# How to embed a YouTube video in a page and protect URL stealing

Tags: html, iframe, video, youtube

I have a website that wants to provide YouTube videos content for logged-in users (I take care of the user login in an SSO style myself).

So, the idea is that the videos should only be seen when embedded in the page (like in an iFrame or similar way). Copying the URL and pasting in another tab, or clicking on the YouTube logo image that exist in a YouTube embedded player, which sends you to the YouTube page of the video - should not be working.

So, the most trivial idea is to make the video private, and then of course only logged in user can see it. But since I do not want to involve Google user per user of my own system, I want to have one "service account" like user, which will be the owner of all my videos. When accessing the video, I can see 2 ways to do this:

1. The link on the page will not be triggering the video directly, but rather arrive to my app server, which will verify whats needed, authenticate to Youtube as the SA user, and .... Then what? I don't want to stream the video myself, but serve it directly from YouTube embedded player.
2. (Not sure it's possible) if within the iFrame I could be somehow set to be logged in as the SA user, then the process would work fluently (something like being in a different Chrome profile, within the iFrame).

Not sure either is feasible here, and what other alternatives exist, so any suggestion would be welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I know you specified YouTube embed, but I found an **alternative** because I could not find the solution to this question when I had to implement the same thing for a client earlier this year.

The workaround that I used was that, since they are `private` videos, it does not matter where they are hosted. So, I convinced the client to used `google drive` to store the videos and embeded them from there. Works like a charm, the player is a little cleaner and there is no YouTube logo.

Hope this helps,

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

The only way I see of making it only accessible from your own page would be to `lock the embed to a specific domain` [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=locking%20video%20embed%20to%20domain), and if you want to host with a video service, the only one I can think of is [Vimeo Plus](http://vimeo.com/plus) and use the Domain Level Privacy.

Comment: One thing I do not understand about this solution - if I host the file in Google Drive, doesn't that mean I also have to use some other kind of embedded player? Can youtube embedded player run non-YouTube videos?

Comment: google drive videos can be embeded with the same `iframe` method youtube videos can.

Comment: I see. Ok.. but regardless if it's YouTube or G. Drive, if the video is private, how do I make it accessible only within the iFrame?

Comment: Well no, it is accessible from the direct link too. The only way I see of making it only accessible from your own page would be to [lock the embed to a specific domain](https://www.google.com/search?q=locking+video+embed+to+domain), and if you want to host with a video service, the only one I can think of is [Vimeo Plus](http://vimeo.com/plus) `Domain Level Privacy`